# Using accessor methods internally within a class?

Tags: java, optimization, accessor

I am wondering if using the accessor methods of a class within the class itself will cause any performance problems. I am wondering about Java compilers specifically, but I suppose this is somewhat language agnostic.

Comment: I remember arguing about this with a colleague a few years ago.  I was saying "don't do it, it bloats the code", he was saying "do it, it's useful for debugging and means you don't have to change as much if you want to modify it later to fire a `ChangeEvent`."  Then I said "But it's the same class, it will be easy to modify when needed using Eclipse's refactoring functions." But performance didn't come into it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, newer JVM's are very good at optimizing the bytecode on start up and in-the-fly.

Documentation from J2SE SDK v 1.4.2 (which is already very old, like close to a decade) already mentions that the JVM will inline accessor-calls within a class:

*"The Java 2 release of the Java VM automatically inlines simple methods at runtime. In an un-optimized Java VM, every time a new method is called, a new stack frame is created. The creation of a new stack frame requires additional resources as well as some re-mapping of the stack, the end result is that creating new stack frames incurs a small overhead.
Method inlining increases performance by reducing the number of method calls your program makes. The Java VM inlining code **inlines methods that return constants or only access internal fields.** "* (emphasis mine)  [J2SE SDK 1.4.2_02 Chapter 8 Continued: Performance Features and Tools](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/perf2.html)

Also, I'd make sure that the worst bottleneck of the software actually is < insert whatever you feel is "slow", in this case using accessors within a class >. IMHO, premature optimization is bad, optimizing by guess is even worse, so try to profile and measure that the bottleneck actually is where you think it is, before trying to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I am not actually trying to optimize; this was more like a question that just popped up as I was programming.

Answer (score 1):

The first point is Don't optimize until you have a problem. The second is nothing prohibits you from writing better code. And better here is not to use getters/setters if they don't do something special. Inside the class it is an overhead. In Android Developers guide for example there are the words about the case: it advices to use direct fields access instead of getters/setters.

Comment: One argument for getters/setters is that they're more future proof as they allow implementing internal logic (validation, propagating state changes, etc.) - how often is it legitimate to bypass such stuff in any case (e.g. because the change happens from inside the class)?

Comment: Future proof -- IMHO is doesn't matter here, simple because you can change it anytime you need. However, I don't think that not using accessors buy you anything for normal Java (on small platforms it's probably different).

Answer (score 0):

It is worth remembering that the Java compiler does almost no optimisations.

However the JIT can inline simple methods such as plain getter/setters and so their overhead is significantly reduced or eliminated.

The JVM can even inline up to two virtual methods, something most static compilers don't do.

Answer (score -1):

Accessors are usually not optimized (ie . transformed into direct call to the class property) so you should avoid using them as calling a method means looking for the method in a virtual table : see : http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Optimization_of_Java

Comment: IMHO, the informations in the link are very obsolete. The explanation in the section Myths is plain wrong (although the recommendation of not using final for performance reason is right).